# How do I url unencode in Python?

Tags: python, url, encoding

Given this:
`It%27s%20me%21`

Unencode it and turn it into regular text?

Comment: When you googled, what did you find?

Comment: @S.Lott, when I googled, I found this page!! *boom boom crash*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at `urllib.unquote` and `urllib.unquote_plus`.  That will address your problem.  Technically though url "encoding" is the process of passing arguments into a url with the & and ? characters (e.g. `www.foo.com?x=11&y=12`).

Answer (score 23):

in python2

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.unquote('It%27s%20me%21')
"It's me!"
```

In python3

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.unquote('It%27s%20me%21')
"It's me!"
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [unquote](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) method from [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#module-urllib).

```
>>> from urllib import unquote
>>> unquote('It%27s%20me%21')
"It's me!"
```